# NoMethodError in Admin::ApartmentPostsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am using active admin for my admin panel in Ruby on Rails website. I have this code on my ApartmentPost resource.

```
ActiveAdmin.register ApartmentPost do
permit_params :title, :max_stay, :min_stay, :bed_configuration, :number_of_guests,
                        :features, :description, :admin_user_id, :apartment_number,:latitude, :longitude, :clean_fee, :country, :location, photos: []

 form(html: { multipart: true }) do |f|
f.inputs do
  f.input :title
  f.input :max_stay
  f.input :min_stay
  f.input :bed_configuration
  f.input :number_of_guests
  f.input :features
  f.input :description
  f.input :country
  f.input :location
  f.input :apartment_number
  f.input :latitude
  f.input :longitude
  f.input :clean_fee
  f.input :admin_user_id, as: :hidden, input_html: {value: current_admin_user.id}
  f.file_field :photos, multiple: true
end
f.actions
end
```

So the error I am getting is while creating a new ApartmentPost. The error is:

[image]

I had created a column called rate in AparmentPost but now it is already removed. Still it gives this error.

Here's the table from schema.rb:

```
create_table "apartment_posts", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "admin_user_id",                   null: false
t.integer  "max_stay",                        null: false
t.string   "bed_configuration",               null: false
t.integer  "number_of_guests",                null: false
t.string   "features",                        null: false
t.string   "description",                     null: false
t.json     "photos"
t.datetime "created_at",                      null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                      null: false
t.string   "title",                           null: false
t.string   "country",                         null: false
t.string   "apartment_number",                null: false
t.string   "latitude"
t.string   "longitude"
t.integer  "min_stay",                        null: false
t.string   "location",                        null: false
t.integer  "clean_fee",         default: 100, null: false
t.integer  "property_type_id"
t.index ["admin_user_id"], name: "index_apartment_posts_on_admin_user_id", using: :btree
t.index ["property_type_id"], name: "index_apartment_posts_on_property_type_id", using: :btree
end
```

Here's the code in routes.rb

```
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
```

I am new in Rails and Active Admin. I tried searching the solution everywhere even tried uninstalling active_admin gem and installing again and removing apartment_post resource and generating it again but none og them worked.

Comment: Did you restart `spring` and also your rails server?

Comment: Yes have already tried restarting the server. But is there any different way of restarting spring?

Comment: `spring stop` will stop and automatically restart spring.

Comment: Yup, tried that too. Didn't work :/

Comment: Can you search your codebase for `rate` and see if anything pops up that you might have missed?

Comment: Such a stupid mistake. I forgot to remove `rate` from apartment_post.rb model file. I thought permit_params in resource apartment_post was enough. Thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Posted as answer so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to remove `rate` somewhere in your codebase. Try searching if you missed anything.